# serialVersionUID not declared in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am getting the following error in my Servlet.

```
The serializable class Regstn does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a warning not an error. In your servlet class just add a class variable.

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

I hope your class or any super-class of it, implements Serializable

Comment: `HttpServlet` certainly implements `Serializable`. Otherwise he wouldn't have received this warning :)